# How can I make all entities multitenant with Eclipselink 2.3

Tags: persistence, eclipselink, multi-tenant

I'm working in a Java project where I need to make automatically an application (ear file) multitenant. A minimum configuration (view here http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Development/Indigo/Multi-Tenancy) to enable multitenancy in a given entity is :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMP")
@Multitenant
public Employee() {
  ...
}
```

My goal is to add dynamically the @Multitenant annotation to all entities and my question is: is there a solution other that editing the bytecode to add this annotation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an orm.xml if you don't want to change the code.

You could also use a SessionCustomizer to configure a MultitenantPolicy on each ClassDescriptor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
The first solution doesn't suit me because I should have to indicate all entities classes name.
The second solution is more interesting. Can you detail a little more?

Comment: Ok, I see how to do it.
A small interrogation, how is a MultitenantPolicy set? I mean the parameter passed to setMultitenantPolicy.